# Select latest entry of ForeignKey and return as nested object with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm trying to return a query via the Django ORM that results in this object:

```
[
  ...,
  {
    "id": 1,
    "product_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-03-03T03:34:59.275941Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-03T03:34:59.291653Z",
    "latest_comment": {
      "comment": "Leaving a comment",
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Lennon",
        "profile": {
          "avatar": null
        }
      },
      "updated_at": "2020-03-03T03:34:59.329229Z"
    }
  }
]
```

I have the following models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar", blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Note(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="notes", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "updated_at"
```

I've been able to achieve the structure above with the following code, but it introduces the N + 1 problem.

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=1)

notes = []
for note in product.notes.all():
    try:
        note.latest_comment = note.comments.latest()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        note.latest_comment = None
    notes.append(note)
```

I've been playing around with `prefetch_related` as well as annotations with the `Max` function without much success. I've also been able to write a raw query that can reproduce this using some Postgres and the `json_build_object` function. The reason I'm trying to get the ORM to work is that I'd like to use `CursorPagination` and using `.raw()` or `RawSql()` doesn't seem to be compatible with `CursorPagination`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't exactly add a nested object, rather add some values from `Comment` object using [**`Subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) with queryset like this:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
newest = Comment.objects.filter(note=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
notes = product.notes.annotate(
    comment_author=Subquery(
        newest.values('author_id')[:1]
        )
    ).annotate(
        comment_comment=Subquery(
            newest.values('comment')[:1]
        )
    )
# and so on
```

Alternatively, use [**`prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to reduce db hits, like this:

```
for note in product.notes.prefetch_related('comments').all():
    note.latest_comment = note.comments.order_by('-created_at').last()
    notes.append(note)
```